# Ascendant gap chain of a prime constellation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Given a prime constellation, define its "ascendant gap chain" as the sequence of prime gaps appearing therein sorted in increasing order.

Do all prime constellations of length $k$ share the same ascendant gap chain?

Comment: What is a prime constellation? a prime gap?

Comment: Why don't you answer ? I have the same question...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple#Prime_constellations

Comment: OK , but the largest entry need not be the same, right ?

Comment: It does, as it is the diameter.

Comment: So, with length , the largest entry is meant, not the number of entries ?

Comment: No, length is the number of entries. See https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&source=android-browser&q=length+prime+constellation#sbfbu=1&pi=length prime constellation

Comment: Upto which length have you checked the constellations ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115123/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-peter).

Answer (score 1):

No.  According to Tony Forbes's list [here](http://anthony.d.forbes.googlepages.com/ktpatt.txt), there are six possible patterns of prime 13-tuplets with the minimal width (48):

```
13  48 : 0  6  12  16  18  22  28  30  36  40  42  46  48 
13  48 : 0  4  6  10  16  18  24  28  30  34  40  46  48 
13  48 : 0  4  6  10  16  18  24  28  30  34  36  46  48 
13  48 : 0  2  6  8  12  18  20  26  30  32  36  42  48 
13  48 : 0  2  8  14  18  20  24  30  32  38  42  44  48 
13  48 : 0  2  12  14  18  20  24  30  32  38  42  44  48
```

The third and last of these contain gaps of length 10, but the others don't.  You can find explicit examples of prime 13-tuplets both with and without gaps of length 10 [here](http://anthony.d.forbes.googlepages.com/kt13.txt); for example:

```
10527733922579 + d, d = 0, 2, 12, 14, 18, 20, 24, 30, 32, 38, 42, 44, 48
186460616596321 + d, d = 0, 6, 12, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 36, 40, 42, 46, 48
```